# Can a .NET 4.5 Assembly be invoked from Access 2010?

Tags: .net, ms-access, vba, .net-4.5

Basically, the question is in the title!  I've tried searching for this and have come up with nothing at all.

All I need to know is, is MS Access 2010 capable of invoking a .NET 4.5 dll?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't created the assembly yet, it doesn't necessarily need to be .NET 4.5, could use an earlier framework version, but would rather know if I need to use an earlier version in advance really! :)  I've also never touched VBA or Access, my boss just asked me to do this today so I've got some learning to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason it wouldn't be. You just need to make your DLL COM Visible and then register it on the machine. You can then instantiate and invoke the component via COM from VBA in Access 2010.

If you've never done that before, I would suggest starting to look at the resources here:

[Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx)